# Setting the hostname based on tags from dynamic inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dynamic, ansible, inventory

I am tagging my dynamic hosts in EC2, and I would like to use that tag as a basis for the servers hostname.

The only way that I can think to do this would be to somehow loop over the dynamic inventory results on the "public_ip_address" variable, and then access the "tags.Name" variable to set the hostname...

But I am unsure if this is possible, or the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I figured it out on my own. Access the ec2_tag_Name variable during the host run

```
- name: Set Hostnames
  hosts: all
  tasks:
   - hostname: name={{ec2_tag_Name}}.domain.com
     become: true
```